# Определение речевой ошибки. Стилистика.

Tags: стилистика

Подскажите с данным заданием. "Исправьте предложения, устраняя лексические ошибки.
Укажите разновидности ошибок: выбор слова без учета его значения, речевая
избыточность (тавтология или плеоназм), нарушение лексической сочетаемости,
неверное использование паронимов, синонимов, антонимов."
1. Был провозглашен приговор суда. 2. Большинство выпускников нашей
академии добились успешной карьеры. 3. Мы хотим сотрудничать вместе с
Вами. 4. Пишите Ваши инициалы полностью. 5. Главная суть уголовного дела
изложена в протоколе. 6. Отделу мониторинга было поручено разработать
квалифицированные требования к экспертам областного уровня. 7. Внедрение
новых технологий сыграет должный эффект в развитии экономики. 8.
Преступник стал жертвой правосудия. 9. Серьезные дефекты в проведении
следственных мероприятий обнаружились только на суде. 10. Верховенство права и закона – общий и заглавный принцип правового государства.

Comment: Ох, как много вопросов! Ответьте хоть на что-то сами, а мы дополним!

Comment: это и есть остатки...

Answer (score 5):

1.Был оглашен приговор суда (***провозглашён - неверное использование паронимов***).   2. Большинство выпускников нашей академии сделало (-и) (***добились карьеры - нарушение лексической сочетаемости)*** успешную карьеру. 3. Мы хотим сотрудничать ***[сотрудничать вместе - речевая избыточность, плеоназм]*** с Вами.4. Пишите Ваши ***[инициалы - выбор слова без учета его значения]***имя, отчество и фамилию полностью.  5.***[ Главная -речевая избыточность,плеоназм]*** Суть уголовного дела изложена в протоколе.6. Отделу мониторинга было поручено разработать ***[квалифицированные -выбор слова без учета его значения]*** требования к экспертам областного уровня.7. Внедрение новых технологий ***[сыграет должный эффект - нарушение лексической сочетаемости]*** сыграет важную роль (?) в развитии экономики. 8. Осуждённый стал жертвой неправосудия   ***[жертвой правосудия -нарушение лексической сочетаемости, неверное использование антонимов]***. 9. Серьезные ***[дефекты- неверное использование синонимов]*** нарушения (или недостатки) в проведении следственных мероприятий обнаружились только на суде. 10. Верховенство права и закона – общий и ***[заглавный- неверное употребление паронимов]*** главный принцип правового государства.

*Примерно так. Думаю,что коллеги подкорректируют, если что-то им не понравится.Удачи!*

Comment: В шестом: вместо квалифицированные - квалификационные, неверное употребление паронимов.

Comment: Спасибо, Лара, согласна. Шестое предложение мне никак не давалось))).